# Can you put more than one Email address in an SQL field?

Tags: php, sql, forms, email

My client has a php form that was multiple locations across the county, each location has a different email. They want to have a copy of the each email sent to the mail office.

Can I just add the office email into the SQL field for each location?

Comment: *"Can you put more then one Email address in an SQL field?"* ---  Sure, why not. Just as long as the SQL is properly syntaxed/formatted. Got some code you need to share? Something you've tried and are having trouble with?

Comment: It really depends on your validation process and a number of other things. Yes you can put more than one email in a field, but how does the code interact with it?  How would your sendmail know what was going on?

Comment: Also, you could always just put cc office email in the mailer script. No SQL needed.

Comment: Sure, we'll await you next question how do I query out records from this multi-value column. The usual first response why oh why oh why did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a SQL problem but a schema design problem. In a properly normalized database you'd have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE office_emails (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  office_id INT,
  address VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Then you have a one-to-many association between offices and email addresses for these offices. You can select out for a given office with:

```
SELECT address FROM office_emails WHERE office_id=?
```

Remember that email addresses are just strings as far as SQL is concerned, so you can do whatever you want to store them.